# TTF not displaying in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, truetype

Im getting the following errors in Firefox. The True Type Font Carlito will not show in Firefox. However I've tested in Firefox on another computer running win 8.1 and it shows. It also used to show and shows fine in Chrome and IE. I downloaded the font from here https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/carlito . What's also interesting is that I have a program called stylizer installed on the same machine and it's version of firefox displays fine.

```
downloadable font: Layout: lookup flag asks for mark attachment that is bad 256 
downloadable font: Layout: Failed to parse lookup 1 
downloadable font: GSUB: Failed to parse lookup list table 
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer
```

I know there was an issue awhile back where some google fonts would display differently if you had them installed on your system. I have removed the font and it makes no difference.

Here is my CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CarlitoBold';
    src: url('/ttf/Carlito-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CarlitoBoldItalic';
    src: url('/ttf/Carlito-BoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CarlitoItalic';
    src: url('/ttf/Carlito-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CarlitoRegular';
    src: url('/ttf/Carlito-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

As I mentioned before, this used to work then all of the sudden it's not.

Ok, I have tested in Firefox 43 and there is no issue. I have tested on multiple machines with Firefox 44 and the issue is replicated.

From what I can see there is an issue with Firefox 44 using the font Carlito from fontlibrary.org.

My question is that I am asking for information on the error messages presented in developer tools.

Comment: Looking for information about the error messages.

Comment: Also note: when using the fontlibrary.org api I get the same errors. Wondering if this is an issue with the latest release of firefox <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/carlito" type="text/css"/>

Comment: Removed my CV after the edit

Comment: I have the same issue. After Firefox update 44, it started to ignore my font as far as I know. It works on IE. I think this is a bug, I think I read something about font related update on this version. I'm using an offline font.

Comment: I downloaded the same font from a website with that font working and replaced it with my font. It's working. I think it's a font related problem and Firefox is not letting it slide anymore after this update.

Comment: Here we go, as soon as the answer comes out, it's 100 websites that need the update... sigh!!!

Comment: Just ran into the same issue, installed FF 43 and did some testing. This only happens in Windows 10 and OSX. I can't reproduce this behavior on my other Windows Installations (XP, Win7, all under Parallels). Also the CSS warning doesn't show up in the console ...

Comment: All platforms are affected. Linux, windows and Mac. Only happens on firefox 44 as far as I Know, and seems to affect only this font so far. Not sure why.

Comment: Can someone post the link to the working font... tried 3 and still have not found one file that works as @MahanGM said

Comment: @Graben I don't use the font that OP said. I'm using a different font. If you have this problem, try to change the font or find one that works on the other websites.